# How to substitute Sendgrid template variables? (in node-js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, templates, sendgrid

It seems to be a simple parameter I'm missing but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what it is.

This is the request I'm sending with '@sendgrid/mail':

*email.js:*

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

function emailRequest() {
    msg = {
      to: 'test+10@gmail.com
      from: 'info@owner.io',
      subject: 'Receipt for Business Expenses',
      template_id: 'db6d11ae-41e4-4e1a-a71b-f5368eb21c9c',
      personalizations: [
        {
          to: 'test+10@gmail.com,
          from: 'info@ownr.io,
          subject: 'Receipt for Business Expenses,
          template_id: 'db6d11ae-41e4-4e1a-a71b-f5368eb21c9c',
          substitutions: {
            ':firstname': 'Bobba',
            ':ordernumber': 'WHAAA',
            ':orderdate': 'today',
            ':ordertime': 'NOW!',
          },
          custom_args: {
            ':firstname': 'Bobba',
            ':ordernumber': 'WHAAA',
            ':orderdate': 'today',
            ':ordertime': 'NOW!',
          },
        },
      ],
      sub: {
        ':firstname': 'Bobba',
        ':ordernumber': 'WHAAA',
        ':orderdate': 'today',
        ':ordertime': 'NOW!',
      },
      substitutions: {
        ':firstname': 'Bobba',
        ':ordernumber': 'WHAAA',
        ':orderdate': 'today',
        ':ordertime': 'NOW!',
      },
    };

  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

  return sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(response => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });
}
```

The email sends, but I'm still getting unsubstituted templates:

[image]

The source code for sendgrid-nodejs mail.js seems to say that as long as there is 'substitutions', it will initialize the mailing class with those substitutions but it's not working:

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/helpers/classes/mail.js

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html

How do you properly substitute variables into templates? Am I using the wrong package?

Comment: Thanks for posting. I have been trying to get an answer from their support for almost two weeks now. Their documentation is awful and the support is not much better. Thanks for posting, will try your answer below!

Comment: Glad I could help. Documentation was pretty spread out but I was able to find a little nugget in there after digging through the Github issues about these substitution wrappers here:

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#transactional-templates

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a bit more digging, I found the answer in the issues section of their github. I was missing 'substitutionWrappers'. To get it working, all I had to do was add 'substitutionWrappers' to the message along with 'substitutions':

```
const msg = {
    to: 'test@email.com'
    from: 'info@gmail.io',
    subject: 'Receipt for Business Expenses',
    template_id: 'da6db3ae-41e4-4e1a-a71b-f5368ab41c9c',
    substitutionWrappers: [':', ''],
    substitutions: {
      firstname: 'Bobba',
      ordernumber: 'WHAAA',
      orderdate: 'today',
      ordertime: 'NOW!',
    },
  };
```

Comment: It worked! You solved what 4 SendGrid employees over two weeks have yet to answer for me. Which I could 2x my upvote.

One follow up, my email is not coming in as HTML (though I am using an html template) when I get it in Gmail. Were you able to get an HTML formatted email?

Comment: Wish I could help with the HTML stuff but we were just handed the templates and they worked without question. Definitely is formatted and styled though I'm not sure how they went about it.

Comment: No worries, just figured it out. The example that Support gave me had the "text" param in the sendmail call. When removed it, the template used the expected HTML version. I guess sending the "text" alternative usurps the template. I also just noticed that the template builder has a "text version" as an option so I can edit it there. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Here is a full example: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#transactional-templates

If you have any ideas on how we can better document this, please let me konw, or PRs for swag are accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to specify the substitution wrappers as it will assume that you're using Handlebars templating by default.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'recipient@example.org',
  from: 'sender@example.org',
  templateId: 'd-f43daeeaef504760851f727007e0b5d0',
  dynamicTemplateData: {
    subject: 'Testing Templates',
    name: 'Some One',
    city: 'Denver',
  },
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

[Check documentation to learn more](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/docs/use-cases/README.md#email-use-cases)